# How to make a dynamic filter? Android SDK Java

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, retrofit

Help to realize the idea with the application. The application receives JSON from the site, and displays information on the screen (for example, games (image, name of the game, creators, year of release and description)). This is all parted, got the data through the retrofit and output them through recycleview. There is no problem with this, but I can’t think of a filter implementation. The filter must be dynamic, for example the creators and year of release. Activation opens where the CREATORS list goes down and the checkboxes with the studios name go down, and the YEAR of the ISSUE and the checkboxes with the year of release also go after it (only the creators and the year must take information from the data they received from the server via Jason). The idea is to have the first standard check box of the type all, which allows you to immediately output everything that is right at the start of the application, and then click the filter button and choose exactly what interests you. And there should be a button that all this update and returns with specific parameters. And I saw there is a button like a cross on the upper right (above on the actionbar), which possibly cancels everything and sets it back to its original position (all checkboxes only). I really hope for your advice and tips on how to implement this application. Thanks to all

Here is a good example of a filter (I need this one) https://pp.userapi.com/c851332/v851332451/e7308/hhiO3IOHPsg.jpg

in fact, a separate activity, which is dynamically filled with checkboxes on the results obtained from JSON (tobish the name, year, etc.)

POJO class value:

public class Value {

```
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;
@SerializedName("year")
@Expose
private String year;
@SerializedName("genre")
@Expose
private List<String> genre;
@SerializedName("director")
@Expose
private String director;
@SerializedName("desription")
@Expose
private String desription;
@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
private String image;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getYear() {
    return year;
}

public List<String> getGenre() {
    return genre;
}

public String getDirector() {
    return director;
}

public String getDesription() {
    return desription;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}
```

}

POJO class for list value:

public class Example {

```
@SerializedName("values")
@Expose
private List<Value> values = null;

public List<Value> getValues() {
    return values;
}
```

}

MainActivity:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private static final String TAG = "MoviesApp";

RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.filters:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, FiltersActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rc_movies);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    JSONPlaceHolderApi service = NetworkService.getJSONApi();
    Call <Example> call = service.getValues();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
            Example data = response.body();

            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                if(data != null) {
                    MoviesAdapter moviesAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(MainActivity.this, data);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(moviesAdapter);

                    Log.i(TAG, "Response call");
                }else{
                    Log.i(TAG, "Data is null");
                }
            }else{
                Log.i(TAG, "Response does not successful");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Failure call");
        }
    });
}
```

}

And i cant make FiltersActivity so that it works according to the condition

Sorry for bad english :C

Answer (score 0):

...

Hi Daniil,
using a second activity for filter is not a bad idea in my opinion.
The problem is to update the list every time you apply a new filter because you have to store your filters values somewhere and then update the list after apply.

I suggest you to try using a shared class between activities (maybe a ViewModel) and if you wanna allows the generation of filters you can build the interface of the second activity in a dynamic way during your network call using the values you have received.

All filters value can be stored inside the viewmodel into an appropriate object during the network call (using a background operation to not freeze the UI).

When you call the second activity the shared class will be interrogated to obtain the filters and in the onCreate method you can generate the corresponding Views programmatically from the data you have received after the interrogation.

Also,to make sure the "apply filter" event will be intercepted by the first activity you can use an Event Bus Library, a LiveData Object or an Observer Pattern (Listener) according to the ones that fit your architecture best. When the first activity receives the event you can force and offline filter operation in your data and update the RecyclerView using a notifyDataSetChange().

Another architectural approach is to use a single activity and two fragments, but it require more code despite it's flexibility.This approach fits best with Viewmodels and Livedata and allows you to manage only one activity lifecycle (no worries about the kill of the non focused activities by the system).

Hope this will give you some hints/help.

Cheers